# Tastypie build_filters access tp request.user

Tags: tastypie

Is there any way to access the user that initiated the request in build_filters override in tastypie.

I want to use the logged in user to give context to one of the filters for example filter contains the word Home and i want to use this as a lookup to the requesting users locations to find their home address.

If build filters took the request as an argument this would be easy as i could simply call

```
request.user.get_profile().userlocation_set.get(name_iexact=filters['location'])
```

Is there anyway to force the user into the list of filters or alternatively enrich get parameters before they are passed to build_filters.

Answer (score 1):

There still isn't a great method for this. I'm currently overriding `obj_get_list` like so, so that I can manually pass the bundle object to `build_filters`:

```
def obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    filters = {}

    if hasattr(bundle.request, 'GET'):
        filters = bundle.request.GET.copy()

    filters.update(kwargs)
    applicable_filters = self.build_filters(filters=filters, bundle=bundle)

    try:
        objects = self.apply_filters(bundle.request, applicable_filters)
        return self.authorized_read_list(objects, bundle)
    except ValueError:
        raise BadRequest("Invalid resource lookup data provided (mismatched type).")
```

There is currently an open pull request for this change:

https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/pull/901

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to do that. I generally 'cheat' by adding the code into apply_authorization_limits where the session is available.